# On payment page Paypal option is not visible

Tags: magento2

I had configured paypal option. I am able to see paypal button on cart and product detail page.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `"Billing Agreement Signup" to "Yes"`

Comment: I have already changed to yes

Comment: Can you confirm cache cleared? Also is there any error in js console?

Comment: yes cache is cleared and also there is no error in js console

Comment: Can you please add screeshot of admin setting where the changes are made?

Comment: i have added screenshot

Comment: You are using Country India while checking?

Comment: yes, I have added India

Comment: No I mean when you are adding shipping address, you are using shipping details for India?

Comment: yes, this website works only for India